# css span:hover doesn't work in IE but works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, html

This is the basic structure of my jsp page.

```
<div><span><span>   </span</span></div>
```

The content of the innermost span tag is hidden by default. When I hover over the content of the outer span tag, it should display the content of the innermost span tag. When I run this in IE8, it successfully hides the inner span tag but when I hover over the outer span tag, it doesn't display the inner span content.

However when I run the same thing in Firefox, it works like a charm. What can I do to make it work in IE8?

This is the jsfiddle link that I created with the generated html [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7s4Np/5/)

Note: If I change the outer span to link(a) tag, it works in IE. But I have to use span tag.

jsp page

```
<div id="tooltip1">
<span id="<%=i %>" class="content" 
                   onmouseover="this.style.color='#F50A16';showStopsInfoPopup('<%=stop %>', <%=i %>)" 
                   onmouseout="this.style.color='#050505'" 
                   onClick="search(this)" value=<%=stop %>>
    <%=stop %>
    <span id="stopsInfo<%=i%>">Hi</span>
</span>
</div>
```

css

```
#tooltip1 { position: relative; }
#tooltip1 span span { display: none; color: #FFFFFF; }    
#tooltip1 span:HOVER span {display: block; 
               position: absolute; 
               background-color: #aaa; 
               color: #FFFFFF; 
               padding: 5px; 
               height: 10px}
```

javascript

```
function showStopsInfoPopup(stop, index){
    jQuery(function($) {
        $("#stopsInfo"+index).load("showStopsInfoPopup.do?stop="+stop);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid inline event handlers whenever you can. It isn't that much harder to bind them using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks.. I have never used jquery. Can you point me to an example with bind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this could be done in a much easier way using jQuery as shown below:

```
$(".content").on("mouseover", function(){
    $(this).find("span").show();
});

$(".content").on("mouseout", function(){
    $(this).find("span").hide();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
   <span class="content">
   <span id="stopsInfo<%=i%>">Hi</span>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have hardly used jquery before but I'll try this out.

Answer (score 2):

:hover just won't work in older browsers, except with the a tag. If you have to use a span tag, then you'll need to add both span and a. This is how most menus work.

In your case:

```
<div><a><span>default text <span>(hover text)</span></span></a></div>
```

And the css:

```
a {text-decoration:none;}
a span span {display:none;}
a:hover span {display:inline;}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/cV4qp/

The alternate option is to use JavaScript instead of css.

Answer (score 1):

Because that pseudo selector supported with CSS3 and before that it is only for a tag. That s why a tag is working on IE as well. To support this you should attach mouseover and mouseout event for IE browser you can do that easily with a hack and jquery.

Just added simple changes to JS and css It should do the trick.

JS and hack only for IE

```
$(document).ready( function () { 
      $("#tooltip1 span.content").hover(
             function () { 
                      $(this).toggleClass("hover"); 
             });
```

});

CSS

```
#tooltip1 { position: relative; }
#tooltip1 span span { display: none; color: #FFFFFF; }    
#tooltip1 span:HOVER span { display: block; 
                            position: absolute; 
                            background-color: #aaa; 
                            color: #FFFFFF; 
                            padding: 5px; 
    height: 10px}
.hover
{
    color:red;
}

.hover span 
{
    display:inline;
    color: blue !important;
}
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7s4Np/7/

Comment: Can you please tell me what kind of hack and what feature of the jquery as I haven't used jquery much before?